# How to remove custom my account page link in left panel in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I have a custom module.I created the my account page menu and page.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-rewardpoints-link" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">rewardpoints</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Reward Points</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

I want to to show the menu when the module is enable from the back end.

```
$enable = $this->helper('Eight25media\Rewardpoints\Helper\Data')->getGeneralConfig('rrpoints/enable');
```

I can check from my controller to remove the page but my question is **how to remove in my account page left side menu section?**.

Comment: You can use `ifconfig` in block to check your module is enabled or not

Comment: Thank you.can you explain more please?

Comment: Check @keyur answer you can use `ifconfig="section/group/field"` as your `system.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ifconfig` feature as commented by [@Prince](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/35758/prince-patel), like

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-rewardpoints-link" after="-" ifconfig="ADD/YOUR/ACTIVE">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">rewardpoints</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Reward Points</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

In `ifconfig` you can add your module config condition. like `ifconfig="section/general/active"`

Answer (score 2):

You can check `ifconfig` in your layout using below code

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="your_section/group/field" name="customer-account-navigation-rewardpoints-link" >
```